# Imported CSV into R, Missing Values Become "" instead of NA

Tags: r, csv, stringr

I tried this command

```
df<-read.csv("filename.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

For both, `num` and `int` variables, missing values are read as `NA`. However, for `chr`, missing values are read as `""` instead. When I take the command `is.na("")`, it returns a FALSE. How do I rectify this?

I tried:
`str(replace,"",NA")`, but it would not work.

Comment: Hi @HNSKD, could you give a sample of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `?read.csv`, especially the argument `na.strings`.

Comment: I guess I should change it to na.strings="". Anyway thanks!

Comment: Jup, that's what I wanted to point you to. Feel free to accept this as your answer.